# how to filter an array of objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, json, angular, filter

I have a json that has the "periods" array inside, I already have the filter code working the way I want, but I can't access the properties inside the json

the json  `this.transporte`

```
[ { "id": 1, "emp_id": 1, "nome": "Retirada na Loja", "tipo": "RETIRA", "subtipo": null, "latLng": [-25.45264, -49.26653], "vFreteMin": 0, "vFreteGratis": null, "periodos": [ { "id": 8, "transporte_id": 1, "ativo": 1, "periodo": "Comercial (das 8h às 19h)", "corte": "16:00", "data": null, "week": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] }, { "id": 16, "transporte_id": 1, "ativo": 1, "periodo": "Domingos ou Feriado (Das 9h as 14h)", "corte": "12:00", "data": null, "week": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] } ] }, { "id": 2, "emp_id": 1, "nome": "Frota Própria", "tipo": "FROTA", "subtipo": null, "latLng": [-25.4522, -49.267], "vFreteMin": 0, "vFreteGratis": 80, "periodos": [ { "id": 4, "transporte_id": 2, "ativo": 1, "periodo": "COMERCIAL (9h as 19h)", "corte": "16:00", "data": "2022-03-24", "week": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] }, { "id": 17, "transporte_id": 2, "ativo": 1, "periodo": "Domingos ou Feriados (Das 9h as 14h)", "corte": "09:30", "data": null, "week": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] } ] }, { "id": 20, "emp_id": 1, "nome": "Correios (PAC)", "tipo": "TRANSP", "subtipo": null, "latLng": [-25.4522, -49.267], "vFreteMin": null, "vFreteGratis": null, "periodos": [ { "id": 18, "transporte_id": 20, "ativo": 1, "periodo": "Comercial (Das 8h as 18h)", "corte": "17:30", "data": null, "week": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] } ] } ]
```

the filter

```
filterPeriodos() {
let object = this.formGeral.value.data;
let jsDate = new Date(object.singleDate?.jsDate);
jsDate.setUTCHours(23,59,59,999);
this.dataFormat=jsDate
const d = new Date(jsDate );
if (this.storeS.layout.emp.id === 1) {
    if(this.formGeral.value.entregaBool){
        return this.transporte.filter( transpId =>   transpId.periodos.ativo === (1) && transpId.periodos.transporte_id === (this.metodoId) && transpId.periodos.week[d.getDay()] === 1 ) ;
    }
}
return this.transporte;
}


this.transporte.filter( transpId =>   transpId.periodos.ativo === (1) && transpId.periodos.transporte_id === (this.metodoId) && transpId.periodos.week[d.getDay()] === 1 ) ;
```

I'm not able to access the "periodos" array

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are trying to access the array without it's index as given below.

`this.transporte.filter( transpId =>   transpId.periodos.ativo === (1) && transpId.periodos.transporte_id === (this.metodoId) && transpId.periodos.week[d.getDay()] === 1 );`

`periodos` is an array so to access it's object's properties you need to provide index something like this .

`this.transporte.filter( transpId =>   transpId.periodos[index].ativo === (1) && transpId.periodos[index].transporte_id === (this.metodoId) && transpId.periodos[index].week[d.getDay()] === 1 );`

Note - Here, index will be as per your business requirement and can be like 0,1,2...n.
considering n is the length/ last index of the array.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to analyze all the objects in the array without having to put 0,1,2 to go through the position?

Comment: Then, You need to use forEach for the transporte array and inside that use filter on periodos array, as you want periodos for your result .. 

this.transporte.forEach((trans)=> const resultArr = this.transporte. periodos.filter((perdiod)=> //condition will go here))

Comment: I tried the code
return this.transporte.forEach((trans)=> const resultArr = this.transporte. periodos.filter((perdiod)=> ( perdiod =>   perdiod.ativo === (1) && perdiod.transporte_id === (this.metodoId) && perdiod.week[d.getDay()] === 1 )

Comment: what would be the const resultArr?

Comment: I had never used foreach before, hence the question

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
this.transporte.filter(transpId =>transpId.periodos?.filter((p)=>p.ativo === (1) && p.transporte_id === (this.metodoId) && p.week[d.getDay()] === 1 ));
```

Comment: friend, it seems that the filter is not working, it returns all array objects

Comment: As you are applying filter method on transporte array, that's why you are getting data in the format of transporte only..

Comment: I don't understand, I believe that this filter is not working, because it does not change according to the data in the array

Comment: I'm trying to analyze the code, why the filter is not running